# Linear order of the quotient generated from Vitali relation implies non-measurability of subset of reals

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

Vitali relation, $a,b\in\Bbb R;\ a\sim b\iff a-b\in\Bbb Q$, is used to prove that there exists a non-measurable set of reals: we look at $A=\Bbb R/\sim$, from each $a\in A$ we take $b_a\in a$, then $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{b_a\}$ is the desired set.

This construction require choice function for the power set of $\Bbb R$, and without some kind of axiom of choice there is no guarantee such function exists(it can be seen by, for example, Solovay's model).

I remember reading the following:

> In $\sf ZF$, $\Bbb R/\sim$ has a linear order implies the existence of of non-measurable subset of the reals.

This fact will also imply that compactness implies non-measurable set of reals, so my question is: what proof is there for the above theorem?

Comment: For compactness there is a direct route. Or rather, more direct. It implies the Ultrafilter Theorem. Then show that any free ultrafilter must violate the 0-1 Law in $2^\Bbb N$ with its standard measure. Since all Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic, this implies there is a non-measurable set of reals. Or, if for you "reals" is just $2^\Bbb N$ (because all Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic), then it implies that immediately.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26861/explicit-ordering-on-set-with-larger-cardinality-than-r/26893#26893

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for giving the reference, I will read it soon. But I still wish for proof for the above theorem if possible(as it is very interesting by itself)

Comment: It *is* a proof of the theorem you ask for.

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh, thanks! I will look at it soon!

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's a clever argument (maybe Fubini-style?) that the relation $x\trianglelefteq y\iff [x]_\sim\prec[y]_\sim$ - where "$\prec$" is the putative linear order on $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ - is a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is just as good). I don't immediately see it, but I remember it being fairly short.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see, if you remember the argument please let me know(or if you remember a reference)

Comment: @NoahSchweber can you look at my answer and see if it is good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking help from @Noah comment and from @Wojowu:

Let's assume the contrary, that is, $\mathbb R/\sim$ is linearly ordered but every subset $\mathbb R^2$ is measurable we may use the ergodicity:

Let $\prec$ be the linear order of $\mathbb R/\sim$, and define $x\triangleleft y\iff [x]_\sim\prec[y]_\sim$. Then either $\triangleleft$ has measure $0$ or $\triangleleft^c=\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim\succ[b]_\sim\}\cup\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim=[b]_\sim\}$.

We may notice that $\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim=[b]_\sim\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}\{(x,y)∈\mathbb R^2\mid x-y=q\}$, which is countable union of lines, so has measure $0$, and $\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim\succ[b]_\sim\}$ has the same measure as $\triangleleft$, so in both cases we get that the measure of $\mathbb R^2$ is $0$, which is contradiction.

Comment: My measure theory is a bit rusty, but why does it have to be the case that the preorder you define is either null or co-null? Moreover, just because $\prec$ and $\succ$ have the same measure doesn't imply contradiction since the measure space is not finite, but $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it is either null or co-null because it is closed under $\Bbb Q^2$-translation, and by assumption it is measurable. And if $\triangleleft$ has measure 0 then $μ(\triangleleft∪\triangleleft^c)=μ(\triangleleft)+μ(\triangleleft^c)=μ(\triangleleft)+μ(\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim\succ[b]_\sim\}\cup\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim=[b]_\sim\})=μ(\triangleleft)+μ(\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim\succ[b]_\sim\})+μ(\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim=[b]_\sim\})=μ(\triangleleft)+μ(\{(a,b)∈\mathbb R^2\mid [a]_\sim=[b]_\sim\})$, those 2 has the same measure and at least one of them is $0$

Comment: @Asaf the same measure alone is not enough, the ergodicity is crucial